# d3 json loading error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm getting a weird error that probably comes from asynchronously loading my data json file.

First off, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd7o7zvy/) with my code and hardcoded data.

Instead of hardcoding the data i want to load it from a json file, like this:

```
var nodes;
d3.json("nodes.json", function(json){
    nodes = json;
});
```

Now i know this code eventually works, because i can just call my update function inside of this block and the data gets drawn. This still gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` which i want to avoid.

This is the errorstack i get in chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
bind @ d3.js:844
d3_selectionPrototype.data @ d3.js:900
update @ example.ts:99
(anonymous function) @ example.ts:280
```

Forgot to add: The error occurs on this line `var points = points = plot.selectAll("circle").data(nodes);`

I edited a bunch of things out of the fiddle, to simplify it.

Comment: can you paste the console.log of the data you get from ajax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you are using

```
d3.json("nodes.json", function(json){
    nodes = json;
});
```

Which is a aync call so initially `nodes` will be `undefined` because `var nodes;` gives nothing to it. During the call and your  `var points = points = plot.selectAll("circle").data(nodes);` already run and throw an error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

You can do one thing :-

```
d3.json("nodes.json", function(json){
   //put your complete logic here
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle does not throw this error. 
But most likely your data isn't ready by the time you are trying to create the circles. Put all the logic that does the creation of the circles (or depends on data) into the callback function of

```
d3.json("nodes.json", function(json){
    //PUT CODE HERE
});
```

and this should work as this code does not get run until JSON is loaded.

Comment: Yes, once the answer went up I saw yours :(  great minds think alike :P

Comment: Bingo for both of us :)